# Battlefield 3 Premium Edition doesnt say I'm premium on Battlelog?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3, battlelog, battlefield-premium

I bought Battlefield 3 Premium Edition about a year ago, and it hasn't said that I'm premium on Battlelog. It doesn't say I have all the content like the ACB-90 knife. When I try to get to use the strategy guides it tells me to buy premium first. I don't get all the content on the premium list but I do have the in game items like expansion packs and weapons. I have this on Xbox 360.

Comment: Did you by chance buy it used from someone?  Or how did you activate it?

Comment: battlefield 3 premium edition is the game with a premium edition code

Comment: Did you redeem the code in the case for Premium?

Comment: yes. of course i did i said code

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to call tech support.

Answer (score 3):

SO two things if this is on your 360, you are going to want to go to your download history and download premium again. The like 160 kb file, this should activate premium in your game again and let you have access to all the stuff. Two if it somehow got unlinked from your account you will need to contact EA and have them look at it and see that you have had premium before to re activate it on bf3.